# Contour integral of $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac1{A-\cos\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm supposed to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{A-\cos\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$

Using a contour of a unit circle, $z=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$.

This is the same as:
$$2\mathrm{i}\oint\frac{1}{z^2-Az + 1}\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

The roots are $z=A\pm\sqrt{A^2-1} $. For the unit circle to enclose both roots, $|A|<1$.

However, the sum of the residue gives zero! The residue at smaller root $= -\frac1{2\sqrt{A^2-1}}$, while the residue at larger root $= \frac1{2\sqrt{A^2-1}}$.

I have a hunch that they should be the same in order for me to use residue theorem.

Comment: How do you know $\int_0^{2\pi}...$ is same as $2\pi\oint ...$

Comment: @Lion the OP does not write $2\pi$, they write $2i$, which comes from the fact that $\cos \theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$ and making the proper substitution into $d\theta$.

Comment: @Hayden OK, I get it. Thank you :)

Comment: In my opinion the answer should be $2\pi i/\sqrt{1-A^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the calculation and I got a different answer.  In particular, I get that

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac {1}{A - \cos(\theta)} d\theta = 2i\oint \frac{1}{1-2Az + z^2} dz$.  Notice that factor of $2$ in the denominator of the second integral.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mustafa Said 's answer, there is a typo on your deduction. But I want to point out that there are also some problems.

Firstly, if $|A|>1$, it is obvious that all the deduction is valid. Although there are two poles that $A\pm\sqrt{A^2-1}$, only $A-\sqrt{A^2-1}$ in the unit circle.

What is more, in your assumption $|A|<1$ (the same situation as $|A|\leq1$), it can easy to check the OP is an improper integral and it is divergence (Consider the easy example that $\int\frac{1}{1-\cos(\theta)}d\theta=\frac{-1}{\tan(\theta/2)}$). Maybe it is seems that residue method is also valid but I think it just the Cauchy principle value.

Comment: Ok, so can I use the residue theorem normally or not?

Comment: For the case that $|A|>1$, the answer is right. But for $|A|\leq1$, it is invalid because the improper integral is divergence.